# Calculate the failure rate using a specific row limit in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr, reshape2

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID <- c("ID300","ID301","ID302","ID303","ID304","ID305","ID306","ID307","ID308","ID309")
Measurement <- c("Length","Length","Length","Length","Length","Length","Length","Length","Length","Length")
PASSFAIL <- c("FAIL","PASS","FAIL","FAIL#Pts","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","PASS","FAIL")

df1 <- data.frame(ID,Measurement,PASSFAIL)
```

**Part1**
I am trying to create a failure rate column computed for each ID. The way I am trying to calculate is using a window of 5 ID's. For example

```
Fail Rate = (Number of Fails)/(Number of Fails + Number of Pass)

ID300 <- (Fails of Row1 to Row5)/(Total from Row1 to Row5) = (3/5) = 0.6
```

Note: In df1, anything that has FAIL in PASSFAIL column is considered a failure.

It should also return NA if the window size is less than 5 and hence my desired output looks like this

```
      ID Measurement PASSFAIL  FR
1  ID300      Length     FAIL 0.6
2  ID301      Length     PASS 0.4
3  ID302      Length     FAIL 0.4
4  ID303      Length FAIL#Pts 0.2
5  ID304      Length     PASS 0.0
6  ID305      Length     PASS 0.2
7  ID306      Length     PASS  NA
8  ID307      Length     PASS  NA
9  ID308      Length     PASS  NA
10 ID309      Length     FAIL  NA
```

**Part2**
Once this is done, I need to recalculate the failure rate for every new ID being added considering the same window of 5. For example, my desired output for this would be

```
      ID Measurement PASSFAIL  FR
1  ID296      Length     PASS 0.4
2  ID297      Length     FAIL 0.6
3  ID298      Length     PASS 0.6
4  ID299      Length     FAIL 0.6
5  ID300      Length     FAIL 0.8
6  ID301      Length     FAIL 0.6
7  ID302      Length     PASS  NA
8  ID303      Length     FAIL  NA
9  ID304      Length FAIL#Pts  NA
10 ID305      Length     PASS  NA
```

I am currently calculating the failure rate by doing something like this, which calculates it for the entire dataframe. I am not knowing how to use loops to calculate sequentially for every ID considering the window size of 5.

```
setDT(df1)
# aggregate
df1 <- df1[, .( FR = (sum(PASSFAIL != "PASS")/.N))]
```

Kindly please provide some inputs.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `filter` or `rollapply` from the `zoo` package. E.g. - `filter(grepl("FAIL",df1$PASSFAIL), rep(1,5)/5, sides=1)` Also note that there is a `by=` argument you can pass to `data.table` to run functions within a group defined by the `by=` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am lost on your Part 2, but here's Part 1 sorted using `stats::filter` and a `grepl` call to search for all the values containing `"FAIL"`:

```
df1$FR <- NA
vals <- na.omit(filter(grepl("FAIL",df1$PASSFAIL), rep(1,5)/5, sides=1))
df1$FR[seq(1,length(vals))] <- vals

df1
#      ID Measurement PASSFAIL  FR
#1  ID300      Length     FAIL 0.6
#2  ID301      Length     PASS 0.4
#3  ID302      Length     FAIL 0.4
#4  ID303      Length FAIL#Pts 0.2
#5  ID304      Length     PASS 0.0
#6  ID305      Length     PASS 0.2
#7  ID306      Length     PASS  NA
#8  ID307      Length     PASS  NA
#9  ID308      Length     PASS  NA
#10 ID309      Length     FAIL  NA
```

Or:

```
rev(filter(grepl("FAIL",rev(df1$PASSFAIL)), rep(1,5)/5, sides=1))
```

If you want to get fancy.

Comment: thelatemail, Thanks for this solution but I get an error saying "Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"" How do I get rid of it? is it because of dplyr?

Comment: I just restarted the R session and ran it again without using dplyr and it worked like charm. Awesome solution. Thank you so much. But I might be using dplyr later in my code? Will that be an issue?

Comment: My part 2 is nothing but a "moving failure rate". since this is actually a time series data, I would like this solution to calculate for every new incoming data point being added to the dataframe. But I think your solution will do that. I might be really stupid to ask that question but I will test it and let you know.

Comment: @Sharath - you can explicitly call `stats::filter()` instead of just `filter` if you have `dplyr` loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try sapply function, also I would declare df1 without factors for good order sake.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID,Measurement,PASSFAIL,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$FR <- sapply(df1$ID,FUN = function(x) {
  if(which(df1$ID == x) > nrow(df1)-4){
    return(NA_real_)
  }else{
    start_ID <- which(df1$ID == x)
    end_ID <- start_ID + 4
    return(sum(grepl("FAIL",df1[start_ID:end_ID,"PASSFAIL"]))/5)
  }
})
```

Comment: This works well but just that it is ignoring the "FAIl#" and only works if the value in the passfail column is either a pass or fail?. Can you please modify it to consider "fail#" also as fail please?

Comment: How can u be so lazy, mate :-), just replace my == to grepl